# Run external PS commands with string

Tags: powershell

I want to run the CheckNetIsolation command from powershell that uses a string variable I have assigned earlier in the powershell script.

When I try

```
.\CheckNetIsolation loopbackexempt -d -n=$thePackage.PackageFamilyName
```

I think it takes the `$thePackage.PackageFamilyName` literally. I want the string it is assigned instead. How can I run this command with it using the string that variable is assigned to?

Comment: Have you tried using `$($thePackage.PackageFamilyName)`? Wrapping the variable in $() is supposed to get the value.

Comment: @DeanOC Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this should work

```
.\CheckNetIsolation "loopbackexempt" "-d" "-n=$($thePackage.PackageFamilyName)"
```

I just use double quotes as string delimiter for params and $() to get the value inside the string.